# Simple question about page layouts and record detail components

Tags: visualforce, lightning, page-layout, record

I am having some trouble trying to do some basic lightning app builder work in my developer org, where I am making an app. I am working on a record detail page for a custom object. I want to have a main panel and a sidebar, each displaying a record detail component, and use one page layout for the main panel and a different page layout for the sidebar. this sounds simple to me but I am unable to make it happen.  Is what I am trying to do supported?

Comment: Hi, just to clarify, are you trying to display the same record in each of the sections, or are you attempting to display to records on that page? Also what have you tried so far.

Comment: Same record in both sections

Answer (score 0):

So, one way to do this is the Sidepanel is defined as a `Related Record` component where:

- Lookup field = `Use this myObjectName`
- There's a quick action on `myObjectName` that updates the object. The fields you use in the quick action's layout will appear on the side panel
- `Update action` = the quick action name